# How to apply a function to a list of data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

i have a list of data frame, let's say 30 (one month), and i have to do some calculations modifications stuff and filling some tables out from the list from each element, so i want instead of replacing every time the name of the data frame of the next one, i want do it automatically, i thought about this but it didn't worked

P.S : my code has nothing wrong with it cause i already check it many times on ons single data frame, my prob is how to repeat this code (and many other lines, this is just a small part of my original code which contain over 500 lines) for each data frame, how can i get acces to the element of the list ???

```
test<-list(day01,day02....,day30)
lapply(seq_along(test), function(x) {
name=deparse(substitute(test[x])) 
jr=as.numeric(substr(name,3,4))
n<-length(test[x]$Date_Heure) 
colnames(test[x])[11]<-"Timestamp"
colnames(test[x])[12]<-"Presence"
#tab$time<-as.POSIXct(with_tz(ymd_hms(Date_Heure, tz = "UTC"),"Europe/Paris"))
for (i in 1:n) 
{
test[x]$Timestamp[i]<-with_tz(ymd_hms(test[x]$Time[i], tz = "UTC"),"Europe/Paris")
} 
})
```

so i tried with names(test), and with test[[x]] and only x instead but i got nothing !!!

For each data frame of the list, i'm gonna use informations from the previous data frame (execpt the fisrt day of course), and it's not just this function, i have a very large code that i'm gonna split to functions and do the same to all again

so if there is a solution for that, or is it possible to not putting my data frames in a list and just do a for loop for each data frame and do what i have to do ?

Comment: remember: in R _calling by value_

Comment: In your lines: `colnames(test[x])[11]<-"Timestamp"` and `colnames(test[x])[12]<-"Presence"`, shouldn't the indexes be `1` and `2` instead of `11` and `12` ?

Comment: no the index 11 and 12, that means the colunms number 11 and 12 that i want to mofify

Comment: @jogo, so hwo should i edit my code ?

Comment: Following @jogo's comment: your function isn't currently returning anything.

Comment: well from what i searched for such thing, i didn't saw a returning value .
should i have another list as return or a new data frame or what ??

Comment: your anonymous function has to return the modified dataframe. than you can do:

 `... <- lapply(..., function(x) { ... })`
IMHO you should lapply() over you list of dataframes **test**

Comment: What do you think of this code snippet: `> tmp = c(1,2,3)` `> var = 1`
`> sapply(tmp,function(x) {var = var+x})`, and what do you think the value of `var` will be after running it?

Comment: the problem is that i can't read the first element in the first palce !!
http://postimg.org/image/auwjtu9ex/

Comment: which code you used for a single dataframe?

Comment: @jojo, the one betwen "name= .." and "Paris", but it's a small part of my code which contain over 500 lines. and of course in my code with single data frame, i have day01 instead of test[x].
i don't know how to get acces to the element of the data frame !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# if for a single dataframe x this is well:
name=deparse(substitute(x)) 
jr=as.numeric(substr(name,3,4))
n<-nrow(x) # length(x$Date_Heure) 
colnames(x)[11]<-"Timestamp"
colnames(x)[12]<-"Presence"
#tab$time<-as.POSIXct(with_tz(ymd_hms(Date_Heure, tz = "UTC"),"Europe/Paris"))
for (i in 1:n) x$Timestamp[i] <- with_tz(ymd_hms(x$Time[i], tz = "UTC"),"Europe/Paris")
```

then you can do

```
modDF <- function(x) {
  name=deparse(substitute(x)) 
  jr=as.numeric(substr(name,3,4))
  n<-nrow(x) # length(x$Date_Heure) 
  colnames(x)[11]<-"Timestamp"
  colnames(x)[12]<-"Presence"
  #tab$time<-as.POSIXct(with_tz(ymd_hms(Date_Heure, tz = "UTC"),"Europe/Paris"))
  for (i in 1:n) x$Timestamp[i] <- with_tz(ymd_hms(x$Time[i], tz = "UTC"),"Europe/Paris")
  return(x)
}
List.of.DF <- lapply(List.of.DF, modDF)
```

Comment: for this small part of my code, at least it worked for changing the names of colums but i get this warning "All formats failed to parse. No formats found.", but i have also to see if it work on all my original code***********************Another thing, how can i get the acces to the previous element of the list, let's say i wanna know the persons who are present yesterday while i'm working on today ???

Comment: in such a function like my modDF() there is no way to do that.
eventually you can use another objekt for your data (e.g. a long dataframe from rbind-ing your dataframes with an extra column indicating the day)

Comment: ok i see, but can you please just correct for me this code, i just wanna loop my list (in this way i may can return to the previous data frame) `test=list(day01,day02...,day30). for (p in test) { }`, but when i wanna use p as data frame i can't, like p$column1

Comment: the problem in your code is, that changing p has no effect an the original list, because p is intern to the for-loop (also _for_ is a function), example:
    `L <- list(BOD, BOD);
    for (l in L) l$demand <- -l$demand;
    L`

Comment: it's not a problen if i write then `table=p`, i'll work on table then the element =table, but how can extract the elemnet to put it in the auxiliary variable "table" ??

Comment: you can do somthing like this: `L <- list(BOD, BOD);
for (l in seq_along(L)) L[[l]]$demand <- -(L[[l]]$demand);
L
### or
for (l in seq_along(L)) { T <- L[[l]]; T$demand <- -(T$demand); L[[l]]<-T };
L`

Comment: yeah thanks, that's helped me, but i have to figure out now how to use the previous data frame .
i'll contuniue my tests on my hole code and i'll give the best answer if i did't get anything else. THANKS man :)